# Как сделать чтобы бот работал в беседах ВК?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Бот неактивен в беседах, что не так?

Код:

```
import vk_api
import time
import random

token = 'Цензура'
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk._auth_token()

smale = ''


while True:
    try:
        messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})
        if messages["count"] >= 1:
            id = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
            body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
            if body.lower() == "давай":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Ок", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
                for sam in range(5):

                    for sam1 in range(5):
                        time.sleep(0.9)
                        vk.method(f"messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": {smale}, "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            else:
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Что? " + str(body.lower()), "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
    except Exception as E:
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Переходите на `LongPoll API` или `Callback API`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Да спасибо это единственное и верное решение! К слову я перешел на LongPoll API для ботов.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вместо этого:

```
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk._auth_token()
```

Написать так:

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
```

По-моему метода `_auth_token()` вообще не существует.

Comment: это не работает